# No visible @interface for 'InstanceName' declares the selector'

Tags: automatic-ref-counting

My name is Bob. I code for the Parks Department of NYC. I'm starting to learn Objective C and have a "Semantic Issue." I must have a blind spot, because I checked all the following code and don't see the problem. Thank you for ant help you can give

"No visible @interface for 'Greeter' declares the selector 'setGreetingText::"

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Greeter.h"


int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        
        Greeter* myGreeter = [[Greeter alloc] init];
        
// error on this line
        [myGreeter setGreetingText: @"Hello Objective-C!!" : @"Hello VIP Objective-C!!"];
        
        [myGreeter issueGreeting];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

======================================

## import "Greeter.h"

## import "NewGreeter.h"

```
@implementation Greeter

NewGreeter *VTS;

- (NSString*) greetingText
{
    return [self greetingText];
}

- (void) setGreetingText:(NSString*) newText01
              andThisToo:(NSString*) newText02
{
    greetingText = newText01;
    [VTS setNewGreetingText: newText02];
}

- (void) issueGreeting
{
    NSLog(@"%@", greetingText);
}



#import "NewGreeter.h"

@implementation NewGreeter

- (NSString*) NewGreetingText
{
    return greeting;
}

- (void) setNewGreetingText:(NSString*) newText
{
    greeting = newText;
}

- (void) issueNewGreeting
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [self NewGreetingText]);
}
```

@end

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "NewGreeter.h"

@interface Greeter : NSObject
{
    NSString *greetingText;
}

 - (void) setGreetingText:(NSString*) newText01
              andThisToo:(NSString*) newText02;

  - (NSString*) greetingText;

  - (void) setGreetingText:(NSString*) newText;

  - (void) issueGreeting;



#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NewGreeter : NSObject
{
    NSString *greetingText;
}

- (NSString*) NewGreetingText;

- (void) setNewGreetingText:(NSString*) newText;

- (void) issueNewGreeting;
```

@end

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NewGreeter : NSObject
{
    NSString *greetingText;
}

- (NSString*) NewGreetingText;

- (void) setNewGreetingText:(NSString*) newText;

- (void) issueNewGreeting;
```

@end

Comment: setGreetingText takes only a single parameter. setGreetingText:andThisToo: takes two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You implement the method named `-setGreetingText:andThisToo:`, but you're trying to use it incorrectly. You need to change your call to:

```
[myGreeter setGreetingText: @"Hello Objective-C!!" andThisToo:@"Hello VIP Objective-C!!"];
```

Notice the `andThisToo` bit.

---

If you're only trying to set your object's properties, then you don't need to expose custom methods for that. Instead, you could do:

```
// In Greeter.h
@interface Greeter: NSObject
    @property NSString *greetingText;
@end

// In Greeter.m
@implementation Greeter
    @synthesize greetingText = _greetingText; // Create a backing instance variable
@end
```

This creates an instance variable setter method named `setGreetingText` and an instance variable getter named `greetingText`. I'd recommend you read up on [creating object properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html).